# textviewArray[i].setText(stringArray[i]); is null

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, for-loop

I created TextView Array and defined every element in array I got an a String array with intent but when I tried to set textview text with elements that received string array with for loop, it returned null
what is wrong with this codes? I am beginner in java and

```
public class dizilisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView player1, player2,player3,player4,player5,player6,player7,player8,player9,player10;
TextView[] players = {player1, player2,player3,player4,player5,player6,player7,player8,player9,player10};
String[] receivedNames;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dizilis);
    player1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1);
    player2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player2);
    player3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player3);
    player4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player4);
    player5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player5);
    player6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player6);
    player7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player7);
    player8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player8);
    player9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player9);
    player10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player10);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    receivedNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("names");
    for (int i = 0; i<receivedNames.length; ++i)
    players[i].setText(receivedNames[i]);

    }
```

}

and logcat

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.easoft.aldimverdim.dizilisActivity.onCreate(dizilisActivity.java:33)

and line 33 is

```
players[i].setText(receivedNames[i];
```

Comment: Please post the code from where you receive the `receivedNames` and screenshot of the error. Because receivedName seems to be Strings to me and you can't use it's length in the loop

Comment: ` i<receivedNames.length;` this seems the error to me. Please post full code once

Comment: Please provide more details. Show your how do you obtain "receivedNames" array

Comment: I edited as you wish

Comment: Add your whole content of `onCreate()` method or whole activity.

Comment: I added all the things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

1) Change your 
from

```
TextView[] players = {player1, player2,player3,player4,player5,player6,player7,player8,player9,player10}
```

in to

```
TextView[] players;
```

2) Move initialization, so after

```
player10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player10);
```

add:

```
players = new TextView[]{player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6, player7, player8, player9, player10};
```

3) When `receivedNames` will be `null`, you can add extra condition, for example:

```
// Check if receivedNames are NOT null
if (receivedNames != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < receivedNames.length; ++i) {
        // here rest of codes
    }
}
```

## Error explanation

1) Line:

```
TextView player1, player2,player3,player4,player5,player6,player7,player8,player9,player10;
```

causes that 10 variables are declared. All of them are `null`s

2) So in next line with:

```
TextView[] players = {player1, player2,player3,player4,player5,player6,player7,player8,player9,player10};
```

declare new array and initializes it with `null` values so you array with 10 `null`s inside.

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

3) When in `onCreate()` you are trying to call `players[i].setText(...)`, the `players[i]` has `null` value. So you call `setText` on `null`. That is the crash reason.

## Full working code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6, player7, player8, player9,
            player10;

    TextView[] players;

    String[] receivedNames;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dizilis);

        player1 = findViewById(R.id.player1);
        player2 = findViewById(R.id.player2);
        player3 = findViewById(R.id.player3);
        player4 = findViewById(R.id.player4);
        player5 = findViewById(R.id.player5);
        player6 = findViewById(R.id.player6);
        player7 = findViewById(R.id.player7);
        player8 = findViewById(R.id.player8);
        player9 = findViewById(R.id.player9);
        player10 = findViewById(R.id.player10);

        players = new TextView[]{player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6, player7,
                player8, player9, player10};

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        receivedNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("names");

        if (receivedNames != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < receivedNames.length; ++i) {
                players[i].setText(receivedNames[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## TIP #1

Good practice is to get index from shorter or "causing more problems", so you can change from:

```
i < receivedNames.length
```

to:

```
i < players.length
```

When you receive less data from `getStringArrayExtra()` = nothing happen (just empty TextViews).

But when you will try to assign to TextView which does not exist or to possition in array which does not exist = CRASH

## TIP #2

If you will have same/similiar issue with loops you can:

- use breakpoints (about build Android app in `debug` mode`)
  or
- add simple `try-catch` block to check which index is causing problem. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < receivedNames.length; ++i) {
    try {
        players[i].setText(receivedNames[i]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem with id = " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are never updating the values in the array. Since you know you are going to have 10 views in the array try the following.

```java
private final TextView[] views = new TextView[10];

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   views[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1);
   views[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player2);
   // ... and so forth
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are first initializing the array with null references to text views and not updating the references there after like `players[index]=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1)`. Instead of doing this ,create an empty array
and then use for loop  for  dynamically getting text view id and push object into the array.

```
public class dizilisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView[] players = new TextView[10];
String[] receivedNames;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dizilis);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      String textViewId="player"+(i+1);
      int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(textViewId, "id", getPackageName());
      players[i]=(TextView) findViewById(resID);
    }
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    receivedNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("names");
    for (int i = 0; i<receivedNames.length; ++i)
         players[i].setText(receivedNames[i]);
}
```